# Align Close Button Inside CSS Cookie Consent Popup

Tags: html, css, cookies, bootstrap-4, cookieconsent

I have a cookie consent popup that I added a close X button to it. 
I need to align the button in the middle of the popup but the button is off the center. 
I know I could set a margin-top to fix the problem but I think that's not the correct way of fixing it.

```
<div class="alert cookiealert" >
    By using our website you agree to our Cookie policy
   <div  class="acceptcookies">
      <div class="x"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.cookiealert {
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 420px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    z-index: 900;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transform: translateY(80%);
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.cookiealert.show {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition-delay: 1000ms;
}

.cookiealert a {
    text-decoration: underline
}

.cookiealert .acceptcookies {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;    
}

.acceptcookies .x {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    transition: transform .28s ease-in-out;
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.acceptcookies .x:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.acceptcookies .x:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}

.acceptcookies .x:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

Here's the code: https://codepen.io/m4573r00/pen/RwWEVWp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it this way, even if you have multiple lines of text, it's centered.

```css
.cookiealert.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 1000ms;
}
.alert{
      position: relative;
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}


.cookiealert {
    font-size: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 420px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    z-index: 900;
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.cookiealert.show {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition-delay: 1000ms;
}

.cookiealert a {
    text-decoration: underline
}

.cookiealert .acceptcookies {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  right: 10px;
}

.acceptcookies .x {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 12px;
    height: 13px;
    transition: transform .28s ease-in-out;
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.acceptcookies .x:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.acceptcookies .x:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 6px; 
    bottom: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}

.acceptcookies .x:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 6px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert cookiealert show" >
    By using our website you agree to our Cookie policy
    By using our website you agree to our Cookie policy
    By using our website you agree to our Cookie policy
   <div  class="acceptcookies">
      <div class="x"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed your example and I was able to get the "x" centered but the "x" has a weird transition when hovering the mouse on it. I spent the 2 hours trying to fix it but I don't know what I'm doing wrong ... 
Here's the code: https://codepen.io/m4573r00/pen/RwWEVWp

My css isn't exactly like your example because you removed the  fade-in and fade-out  transition for cookiealert div ... but Codepen doesn't load that transition.

Comment: @M4573R Does' :hover 'shift down a little bit? This is because the height '12px' center is not calculated accurately,'x' has a line width of '1px'. You want to remove the jitter effect, Change the height from '12px' to '13px'. If you don't want a transition, Just remove 'transition' from '.x '. The above code has been modified

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your help.  ... I wish I was as good as you're.

Comment: @M4573R I also often grope by myself, because I can't find documents to learn like these.

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify your HTML code and use Flex to align the 'x'? Also, remove the `position: absolute` property in `.cookiealert .acceptcookies`

HTML

```
<div class="alert cookiealert d-flex" >
   <div> By using our website you agree to our Cookie policy </div>
   <div class="acceptcookies d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="x"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cookiealert .acceptcookies {
    /* position: absolute; */ /*REMOVE*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;    
}
```

```css
.cookiealert {
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 420px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    z-index: 900;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transform: translateY(80%);
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.cookiealert.show {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    transition-delay: 1000ms;
}

.cookiealert a {
    text-decoration: underline
}

.cookiealert .acceptcookies {
    /* position: absolute; */ /*REMOVE*/
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;    
}

.acceptcookies .x {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    transition: transform .28s ease-in-out;
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.acceptcookies .x:hover {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.acceptcookies .x:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}

.acceptcookies .x:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="alert cookiealert show d-flex">
  <div> By using our website you agree to our Cookie policy </div>
  <div class="acceptcookies d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="x"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's centered but if you look closely the "x" has a weird transition. It's not a smooth transition. I was trying to fix that but I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know transition. Can't help